# Is it possible to get Typescript 2.0 to look at jspm_modules for types?

Tags: systemjs, jspm, typescript2.0

basically as the title - Is it possible to get Typescript 2.0 to look at jspm_modules for types?.

Currently, I duplicate all my deps as node_modules which works but just doesn't seem right..

I have seen the typeRoots property but again, I cant get this to actually work.

any ideas?